# scope g++ pedantic compile

Tags: c++, gcc, include, gcc-pedantic

Is it possible to restict the -pedantic switch for certain files? For example I compile stuff using alsa-lib, which I refer with standard

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
```

however -pedantic panics on this file. I am willing and interested in correcting warning and oddities in my own code, but not in alsa and other unrelated third parties.

Is there a way to scope the -pedantic usage?

Comment: Hmm... about oddities, using `-pedantic` is one of such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, GCC suppresses warnings in system headers, unless you explicitly specify `-Wsystem-headers`. And normally, files included with `<>` from `/usr/include` are treated as system headers. Your question suggests you specifically added something that makes GCC *not* treat it as a system header. You haven't specified which compiler options you're using, but are you adding any pointless `-I*` options that might make `/usr/include` get treated as a non-system header directory?

If all else fails, you can use the `-isystem` to actually add directories as system header directories, but you shouldn't need that here.

**Edit**: after re-reading the question, if you installed alsa-lib in a non-standard path, then my remark that you should not need the `-isystem` option may be wrong: it may be exactly what you need.

Comment: I am in fact cross-compiling for arm so nothing is quite "standard"

Answer (score 2):

You can scope *any* compilation key to one *compilation unit*.

Apperently, if you has multiple compilation units you can use deferent keys to compile them:

```
g++ -pedantic file_that_does_not_use_ugly_alsa.cpp
g++ file_that_uses_ugly_alsa.cpp
```

But you you can not scope keys *inside* compilation unit: code get prepropcessed before compiling, all headers are inlined and actually after macros substitution you may find out that *your* code uses some things, that make compiler panic.